# Is it proper to say “I am easy” to respond “take it easy”

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I just had some conversations with a friend, then it ends, he said “take it easy”, but I wanted it to be funny so I said “I am easy”.

I am just wondering if it is proper to say so and what does it imply by saying so?

Comment: “I am easy” doesn’t really work here. It’s not that you couldn’t make the joke in the right context, but you’d have to know what you’re really saying. It’s not an established phrase in this sense, but _easy_, when applied to people, does have an established meaning: ‘sexually free, consenting easily to sex’. It’s similar to ‘slutty’ in many ways. So your friend tells you to take it easy, and you tell him you’re… sexually promiscuous. Doesn’t really work. If you want to stay colloquial and a bit crude, there’s an old one that goes “If I took it any easier, I’d shit myself!”

Comment: (That last one is more commonly used when someone tells you to loosen up: “If I were any looser, I’d shit myself” makes a bit more sense.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you for your reply, especially the quote you gave me. But I don't agree with you that when I say I am easy, I mean something sexually. Well, I agree easy has that imply, but that's just one possibility. Another situation is when somebody asks what would you like to have for lunch, you can say whatever you like, I am easy. The answer below is pretty much I wanted to express. So what I should say would be "I will take it say", or "I will", or just "will do". Anyway, I wanted to be funny, so I cannot use some common answers, but I have to use a proper one :-D

Comment: You may not mean it sexually, but your listener will likely understand it so, because that’s what “I’m easy” normally means. Using it to refer to lunch options may exist in some dialects, but I’ve certainly never heard it. It sounds very odd to me. I’d understand it in context, but not before wondering what your sexual habits have to do with lunch.

Comment: This is correct. The reason I said I am easy is only because when somebody asks you to calm down, you can respond I am calm, like that actor did in the movie Léon. It's just I didn't realise easy is not calm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were speaking to me, I would get what you mean, but I would be momentarily confused. "I am easy" doesn't really follow "take it easy", and I have only heard the construction "to be easy" in reference to somebody's promiscuity (e.g. "She's easy; she couldn't keep her legs closed if she wanted to.").

The response that conveys what you wanted to communicate would be "I *am* taking it easy."

Comment: so can I even say "I will", or "Will do"?

Comment: @david30xie Correct.

Comment: I **could** be used as sarcasm to suggest you considered the advice presumptuous as well as ill-informed. You would need to be **certain** the listen knew that you both knew the answer was illogical. It then becomes akin to a 2yo child repeating whatever an adult says to irritate them. Probably best to never use it except to a BFF who has made an uncharacteristic _faux pas_.